# Saving a PDF automatically to a predetermined folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro that automates a daily report that I send out each day.  One of my last items is to write a script that saves the formatted excel sheet as a PDF (through a print to pdf option), and save it in a specific folder.  I have the following written, however, it still prompts the user as to where to save it.

What would be a better way, or a way in general, to have it save automatically to a folder somewhere on my desktop?

```
Sub printToPDF()
    Worksheets("general_report").PageSetup.CenterVertically = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="Foxit Reader PDF Printer"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122.aspx)?

Comment: I am teaching myself all this as I go.  I tried to use some of the work from that page, but it throws an error when I try to give it a filename.  I wonder if it is because I am using wrong arguments with wrong objects.

Comment: If you post the code giving the error I can take a look at it for potential errors. Just edit your post and we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work,

```
Sub printToPDF()

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String

    FilePath = "C:\Users\userName\Desktop\" 'Change as per your username

    ActiveSheet.Copy 'Copy a worksheet to a new workbook

    'It saves .PDF file at your Descrop with the name of the worksheet
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FilePath & ActiveSheet.Name, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    'Closing a newly created workbook without saving it
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```